# get 2sxc app data from different portal DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

We are setting up different sites as portals in DNN. Some content will be shared across the different portals.

I'm using the following method to render 2sxc data in a page
http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/using-2sxc-in-webforms-custom-webapi-or-other-razor-hosts-300

However, now i want get the same data in another page of a different portal.

Can any one help with the code so i just put in the source portal id and it can be rendered in a different portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done :)

There's an App Data DataSource, where you can specifiy the portal and app-id (in 2sxc 8.5+). Use this in a visual query or in your code.

http://2sxc.org/en/Docs-Manuals/Feature/feature/9266